PS/2 keyboard partially not working
I have an IBM PS/2 keyboard that worked well until a few hours ago, the problem started while I was using my linux PC as I usually do. I tried to write something and then quickly found out that the B, N, /, Space, arrow down and Numpad minus keys were not working. I tried re-plugging the keyboard (when the computer was off) but that didn't help. I also tried disabling i8042.pnp in kernel options but that didn't help as the keyboard still doesn't work and it also doesn't work in grub. How do I fix this?

Sounds like a hardware problem.

Have you tried cleaning the keyboard?

start by determining where the failure is located

Note that the keyboard is a "computer" in mini-format (sending out key strokes in serial format), so unless you can determine a physical cause for the malfunction (bad button, dirt or liquid entry, ...), it may simply be that the electronics "gave up" (i,e. broke, let out the magic black smoke) in some manner.
